# How to handle AVPlayer in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to work out how to successfully use an `AVPlayer` inside a `UITableViewCell`. Inside my `UITableViewCell` I have a `UIView` subclass that has an `AVPlayerLayer` inside it using this code (given by Apple):

```
class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
         return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
         return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }

}
```

I set the `player` in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` using the following code:

```
let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: cellVideo))
cell.playerView.player = videoPlayer
```

This works fine, however, when the cell is out of view, I don't want the video to play. Should I be setting the `player` to nil, and then when the cell shows again set the `player` again, or should I just pause the video? Or is there another way I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this UITableViewDelegate method, to do what you want when the cell is out of the view:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
   didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, 
           forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

I'd personally stop the video and set the player to nil since `cellForRowAt indexPath` is called when a cell become visible.

Comment: Yes but I'm asking what should I be doing in this function?

Comment: How do you set the view in the cellForRowAt indexPath ?

Comment: cellForRowAt indexPath is called when the view is visible again, so if you always init the player in it, you should probably set it to nil in the didEndDisplaying method

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Yes you should set the player to nil for performance improvements. 
I think you should also set the player to nil in the custom cell class by overriding the prepare for reuse method.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    player = nil
    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```

Also if your goal is to mimick a newsfeed behavior, I suggest looking at [AVPlayer:PrerollAtRate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/prerollAtRate:completionHandler:) it let's you show a thumb at a specific time.

---

You can make use of the delegate methods to pause and resume the player.
Just make sure to cast the UITableViewCell to your custom class

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //cast the cell as your custom cell
    if let myCell = cell as? MyCustomCell
    {
        myCell.player!.play()
    }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //cast the cell as your custom cell
    if let myCell = cell as? MyCustomCell
    {
        myCell.player!.pause()
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah I realise I can pause it, but I'm asking should I just be pausing it or should I set the player to nil. Given that the cell can be used for something other than video, and that there are lots of cells.

Comment: @Tometoyou I see what you mean. I updated my answer for a performance point of view.